# Choosing Redis key names and limit on the number of keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, nosql, redis

I heard a lot about the blazing speed offered by Redis server and hence thought of plugging it into one of my existing Rails applications running on PostgreSQL as the database server.

My question is if I am having about 100000 users on my system and would like to implement a followers/following pattern, I can use Redis' SET datatype or so., but is it a good practice to have 100000 different keys based on user. Is this the right approach to define keys in my current scenario? If so, what is the limit on the number keys on a single instance of redis.

Suggestions on better designing of keys are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis has no problems with handling millions of keys. The theoretical limit is 2^32 keys (see [FAQ](http://redis.io/topics/faq)), so in practice the amount of available memory is the only limiting factor.

Since Redis natively supports only two levels of hierarchy: keys and lists/hashes/sets, having a key per user is pretty much the only option in this case.

Redis uses [very compact representation for small sets](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization), so if most of your users have only a few followers, memory usage should be reasonably low. Adjusting `*-max-ziplist-*` family of configuration options may give results optimal for your particular data set.

By the way, you may be interested in how people at Twitter handle tremendous follower-generated load, using Redis for the part of their stack: [real-time delivery architecture](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Real-Time-Delivery-Twitter) talk is very interesting.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the reply.
But what if I have multiple applications running on the server that uses the same redis instance. Can you typically suggest me what level of optimization I need to follow if I have a 1 GB server. @rkhayrov

Comment: Redis is a fundamentally single-threaded application. All Redis commands are executed atomically, and you can make a series of commands atomic using `MULTI..EXEC` block or built-in Lua scripting (http://redis.io/topics/transactions). All of this makes Redis an excellent message bus/synchronization system for multiple application instances.

I don't think a million-user Rails application can run in 1 GB RAM, especially competing with DB cache for RAM: the question is moot. Only experimentation and profiling can tell.

Comment: Okay that was helpful, so you say the approach that 2 different keys viz., followers and following can easily workout for a scale of approximately about 10000 users right?

Comment: Absolutely. The biggest load will be generated not by keeping followers records, but distributing messages/updates to followers (or collecting and assembling the feed from the followed users) — that's the part worth thinking.